# Merge objects by the same value in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to combine the objects whose prices are the same and add the quantity (`amount`).

Example:

```
[
    {price: 25.1, amount: 32},
    {price: 45.2, amount: 45},
    {price: 25.1, amount: 25},
    {price: 44.0, amount: 13},
    {price: 45.2, amount: 23}
]
```

Result:

```
[
    {price: 25.1, amount: 57}, // 32 + 25
    {price: 45.2, amount: 68}, // 45 + 23
    {price: 44.0, amount: 13},
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Array#reduce` with an object to store the amount for each price.

```js
const example = [
    {price: 25.1, amount: 32},
    {price: 45.2, amount: 45},
    {price: 25.1, amount: 25},
    {price: 44.0, amount: 13},
    {price: 45.2, amount: 23}
]
const res = Object.values(example.reduce((acc,{price,amount})=>
   ((acc[price] = acc[price] || {price, amount: 0}).amount += amount, acc), {}));
console.log(res);
```